# Laravel 5.1 with Asgard CMS, long query execution time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm using Asgard CMS with Laravel 5.1.

One of my models, News, has about 1800 entries and getting them from database takes up to 15 seconds.

On the frontend, getting 1-50 entries is fine. But, in the backend, I take them all and the result is frustrating.

News model uses 3 relations, Category, Tag and Image. And also, along with News, all of these models have Translation models and relations.

I have indexed all the tables related to News. I have upgraded my server to a 3GB 4-core one with SSD storage (VPS). Nothing works for now.

Any ideas to quicken this process?

Comment: Are you using debugbar? How many DB queries does Asgard CMS generate per one page visit?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin it says 5784 queries.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with that number.... There is not enough info with your question to help though

Comment: @Chris I now reduced this number to 115 with Eager Loading, but page loading still takes up to 13 seconds.

Comment: Debugger results after Eager Loading - Views: 70 Queries 116 16.84s 77.5MB 116 statements were executed, 11 of which were duplicated

Comment: How many models are involved on this page? I don't see why its over 100 queries? I think you will have more luck from SO with a more detailed question

Comment: Coming along with CMS, Menus, Settings, Core Translations, Links etc. all models are loaded. So the query count cannot be lower than 100.

Answer (score 2):

You're saying that CMS generates 5784 queries per one page visit. It's a huge number and you should definitely rewrite your queries.

I'd recommend you to learn about [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). You could rewrite your queries manually or try to tune your CMS (I'm not familiar with Asgard CMS, so I can't help you here):

> This loop will execute 1 query to retrieve all of the books on the
>   table, then another query for each book to retrieve the author. So, if
>   we have 25 books, this loop would run 26 queries: 1 for the original
>   book, and 25 additional queries to retrieve the author of each book.
>
> Thankfully, we can use eager loading to reduce this operation to just
>   2 queries.

Comment: Debugger results after Eager Loading - Views: 70 Queries 116 16.84s 77.5MB 116 statements were executed, 11 of which were duplicated

Answer (score 0):

After applying Eager Loading to my models, I have dropped the query count to 117 from 5879. And also the query time is dropped to 13s from 17s.

This is a progress, but it is not enough.

It shouldn't take this much longer to get just 1800 entries. I get millions in that time, in other projects.

Any suggestions? Any point to look for?